# covering space, deck transformation

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $X=(S^1-1)(S^1+1)$ be the eight, $Y=\mathbb{R}\cup\{z+2k\pi+i:k\in\mathbb{Z},z\in S^1\}\subset\mathbb{C}$ and $u(t)=1-e^{2\pi it}, v(t)=e^{2\pi it}+1$
>
> a) Give (per formula) a covering space $p:Y\to X$ with $[u]\in p_{\ast}(\pi_1(Y,0))$
>
> b) Give every deck transformation of $p$.

Hello,

I want to solve this problem but I do not know why.
Do you know which formula could be meant in a)?
Than I can try it myself first.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you perchance mean "let $X = (S^1 - 1)\cup(S^1 + 1)$ be a figure eight"?

Comment: Yes, I mean, that the resulting figure is shaped like the eight.

Comment: formula in a) means that $u|_{[0;1]}$ is considered as an element of $\pi_1(X)$, and the question is "does this element lay in the image of $p_*$?"

Comment: So $p: Y\to X$ and $p_{\ast}:\pi_1(Y)\to\pi_1(X)$ with $[w]\mapsto [p\circ w]$. But I have to finde $p$ first?